# Return an array with element in specific position

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I've been trying to figure this out for a good while now, and I can't solve it.
This function receives an array of names and should return an array containing the middle names. If someone does not have a middle name the array should contain the value null at this index.

I know my code isn't complete, but cannot make work even half of it. The splice method doesn't work whatever I do, and now I'm very lost.

This is my code so far:

```
function getMiddleNames (names) {
let solution =[];
let separated = [];
for(let i=0; i<names.length; i++){
  separated.push(names[i].split(' '));
} 
 return separated.splice(1);
}
```

And the tests:

```
describe('getMiddleNames', function () {
  it('returns [] when passed []', function () {
    expect(getMiddleNames([])).to.eql([]);
  });
  it('returns ["Hannah"] when passed ["Caroline Hannah Jamieson"]', function () {
    expect(getMiddleNames(['Caroline Hannah Jamieson'])).to.eql(['Hannah']);
  });
  it('returns ["Reuben", "Keith", "Clara"] when passed ["Steven Reuben Williams", "Carl Keith Morelli", "Sissel Clara Blomqvist"]', function () {
    expect(getMiddleNames(['Steven Reuben Williams', 'Carl Keith Morelli', 'Sissel Clara Blomqvist'])).to.eql(['Reuben', 'Keith', 'Clara']);
  });
  it('returns ["Reuben", null, "Clara"] when passed ["Steven Reuben Williams", "Carl Morelli", "Sissel Clara Blomqvist"]', function () {
    expect(getMiddleNames(['Steven Reuben Williams', 'Carl Morelli', 'Sissel Clara Blomqvist'])).to.eql(['Reuben', null, 'Clara']);
  });
  it('returns ["Reuben", null, null] when passed ["Steven Reuben Williams", "Carl Morelli", "Sissel"]', function () {
    expect(getMiddleNames(['Steven Reuben Williams', 'Carl Morelli', 'Sissel'])).to.eql(['Reuben', null, null]);
  });
});
```

Could anyone give me a hand? Thank you

Comment: hint: check length of split array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pushing the whole name into your separated array and then splicing that. Which doesn't really work. You need to separate the names and split each one individually:

```js
function getMiddleNames (names) {
    let solution =[];
    for(let i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    let separated = names[i].split(' ')
      solution.push(separated.length == 3 ? separated[1] : null);
    } 
     return solution
    }

let names = ['Steven Reuben Williams', 'Carl Morelli', 'Sissel Clara Blomqvist']

console.log(getMiddleNames(names))
```

This of course assumes there will always be a middle name. It will fail and deliver the last name without it.

You can be a bit more succinct with `map` and test for name length at the same time. Still there will be edge cases (people with four names, etc):

```js
let names = ['Steven Reuben Williams', 'Carl Keith Morelli', 'Sissel Clara Blomqvist']

let middles= names.map(n => {
    s = n.split(' ')
    // s should be an array [first, middle, last]
    // if no middle name it will be [first, last]  and length 2
    return s.length == 3 ? s[1] : null
})
console.log(middles)
```

Comment: It works partially, as returns this error:AssertionError: expected [ [ 'Hannah' ] ] to deeply equal [ 'Hannah' ]
      + expected - actual

       [
      -  [
      -    "Hannah"
      -  ]
      +  "Hannah"
       ]

Comment: @VisualXZ Right, that's because `slice` returns an array. I edited to just return the value. The map version should take care of nulls. Also edited the first to check for no middle name.

Comment: I see it now, thanks for your help. The map version is still a bit far from what I'm able to do at the moment, but trying to get used to it. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function getMiddleNames(names) {
  return names.map(x => getMiddleNameOf(x));
}
function getMiddleNameOf(name) {
  let split = name.split(' ');
  return split.length == 3 ? split[1] : null;
}
```

Comment: Where does `x.getMiddleName` come from when `x` is a string? Answer doesn't appear to have anything to do with code in the question